# Index out of bounds after removing row from 2D array inside for loop

Tags: java

I created a method to remove entire rows from 2D arrays in Java. I created this method because I wanted to remove a row if a certain condition applied. Although, when I use the remove method inside a for loop (for the matrix I am trying to remove) it creates an index out of bounds error. I believe this is because the length of the array is changing. That's why I saved the arr.length inside a variable and I am reducing it inside the for loop. However, I still have an index out of bounds error in java. This is my code:

```
//for loop
for (int index = 0; index < size; index++) {
    if (TheMatrix[index][0] == TheMatrix[0][0]) {
        TheMatrix = removeRow(TheMatrix, index);
        size--;
    }
}

//method for deleting row
public static int[][] removeRow(int[][] TheMatrix, int index) {
    int[][] arrAux = new int[TheMatrix.length-1][7];

    for (int i = 0; i < arrAux.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            arrAux[i][j] = TheMatrix[i][j];
            int z = i+1;
            if (i == index) {
                arrAux[i][j] = TheMatrix[z][j];
            }
            if (i > index) {
                arrAux[i][j] = TheMatrix[z][j];
            }
        }
    }

    TheMatrix = Arrays.copyOfRange(arrAux, 0, arrAux.length);

    return TheMatrix;
}
```

The method for deleting the row works perfectly, the for loop is the one generating the problem.
Any solution would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: How are you instantiating the array? I'm getting no errors from this

Comment: I also don't get any error. Please create a [mre].

Comment: Why the two if-statements in removeRow() ? Just use `>=`

Comment: And there is a MUCH simpler way to remove a row.